# Can I turn off context menu scrolling in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I right-click in the middle of a code editor window in Visual Studio 2010 RTM, a context menu appears. This takes up about a fourth the height of the screen but doesn't show all options. Instead it scrolls up and down when you move the pointer to the top or bottom of the menu. If I click near the top or bottom of the screen, the menu is normal and doesn't scroll.

Can I turn this behavior off? It's stupid. You can't even scroll using the mouse wheel.

EDIT

I reckon this might just be a bug - I've found a few.

Answer (score 12):

This *is* a bug. It's been filed several times on Connect:

- [Please avoid scrolling context menus when vertical space is available](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552294/please-avoid-scrolling-context-menus-when-vertical-space-is-available)
- [Context menus open in scrolling mode while there is place to show the whole menu](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532806/context-menus-open-in-scrolling-mode-while-there-is-place-to-show-the-whole-menu/)
- [Incorrect project context menu height](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533342/incorrect-project-context-menu-height)

... but Microsoft doesn't seem keen to fix it.

I suggest everyone to vote for re-open. Maybe they'll fix it in Service Pack 1.

**Update:**
They fixed it in Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1.

Comment: There is another Connect item here:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552294/please-avoid-scrolling-context-menus-when-vertical-space-is-available   Go vote for it, this behavior is ridiculous.

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft has released a hotfix for this, which fixes the problem for me:

[Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/hotfixes-available-for-scrolling-context-menu-problem/)

Comment: Nice to see it fixed. Currently 3 of the top 5 most voted bugs on the MS connect site concern this issue :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is reported in a number of different places on Microsoft Connect.  This one implies that [it will be fixed](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533342/incorrect-project-context-menu-height):

> Posted by Microsoft on 4/21/2010 at 11:52 AM 
>   Hi,
>
> I want to reaffirm that we hear you on this issue and will fix this asap. Also for reference purposes this issue is a duplicate of Feedback ID: 495221.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, mousewheel scrolling works for me though (it is still very irritating, since the command I use most often are on the bottom of the menu).
I have a Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 6000 with IntelliPoint software 7.0.260.0 on Windows 7 x64, so maybe if you have a Microsoft mouse as well you can try updating the IntelliPoint software.

latest version:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/results.aspx?freetext=IntelliPoint+x64&displaylang=en&stype=ss_rr&nr=10&sortCriteria=Date&sortOrder=Descending

edit:
I just rearranged the commands using Tools->Customize->Commands->Context menu->Editor Context Menus | Code Window. At least for the commands I use most frequently I don't have to scroll anymore :)

greetings,
dalek